# Logging query text without Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, profiler

I'm in the process of porting an old, semi-broken ASP.NET/SQL Server application to PHP/PostgreSQL. Among the torments^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^Hchallenges I'm faced with is that the reporting is done by a series of binary executables, because apparently I've been a bad person and need to be punished. So, I don't have access to the queries in order to port them.

*That's fine,* I thought. *I can run the query profiler and log all* `SELECT` *statements that occur during the nightly report generation.*

Except it turns out that the original developer shaved the cost down by running SQL Server Workgroup Edition, which doesn't include Profiler.

I was considering using triggers to get these queries, but I think I can't use triggers on `SELECT` statements. Reverse engineering the queries is possible, but given the complexity of the database (multiple, often recursive, relationships between tables, loads of similarly-named tables where several haven't been updated in years, and so on) I would prefer to have canonical queries to reference.

How should I go about this? Is there any way to get Profiler running in Workgroup Edition? Is there a way to enable query logging without the profiler? I'm not worried about performance because this app doesn't get particularly heavy use and it's running on a machine that's two sizes beefier than the app requires.

Comment: Have you tried a server side trace or extended events yet?

Comment: Extended Events were added in SQL Server 2008, which is newer than I have to work with. I'm intrigued by Server Side Traces, but I don't see an obvious way to log queries from the MSDN doc page. Continuing to read them, though.

Comment: Oh good call!  You're right you're on 2005.  Please let me know if you need help with the server side trace.

Answer (score 10):

Several options:

1. You could use SQL Server Profiler against the Workgroup Edition server from a different client tools installation of SQL Server Developer, Standard, Enterprise or Evaluation Edition.
2. Use the semi-documented trace flag 4032, as [explained by Tom LaRock](http://thomaslarock.com/2012/02/how-to-trace-statements-without-sql-profiler/).
3. Evaluate third party tools like the free [DataWizard SQL Performance Profiler](http://sqlprofiler.googlepages.com/), [xSQL Profiler](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_profiler/) (free for one instance), or [ExpressProfiler](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/) (BSD Licence).

My preference would probably be option (1), [downloading Evaluation Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29066) if necessary.

Comment: Well dang, I didn't know #1 would even work. Gonna try that. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you tell Profiler not to filter out its own queries, you'd probably see it calling these stored procedures:

- [`sp_trace_create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190362(v=sql.90).aspx) to create a trace
- [`sp_trace_setevent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186265(v=sql.90).aspx) to add or remove events and columns (can only be called on a stopped trace)
- [`sp_trace_setfilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174404(v=sql.90).aspx) to apply a filter to a trace (can only be called on a stopped trace)
- [`sp_trace_setstatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176034(v=sql.90).aspx) to start and stop a trace

As described by [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191443(v=sql.90).aspx), you execute the procedures in this order:

1. Create a trace by using `sp_trace_create`.
2. Add events with `sp_trace_setevent`.
3. (Optional) Set a filter with `sp_trace_setfilter`.
4. Start the trace with `sp_trace_setstatus`.
5. Stop the trace with `sp_trace_setstatus`.
6. Close the trace with `sp_trace_setstatus`.

You will end up with a `.trc` file that you can then open in SQL Profiler or read with [`fn_trace_gettable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188425(v=sql.90).aspx).

Here's an example script to start a trace:

```
declare @rc int
declare @TraceID int

-- create the trace
exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 0, N'trace-filename'

-- set which events to capture
declare @on bit
set @on = 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 2, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 16, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 18, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 16, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 18, @on

-- start the trace
exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in dynamic management views.  AFAIK, they work just fine in Workgroup Edition.

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579092/tsql-get-last-queries-ran

Comment: This is likely my SQL Server naivete, but I'm getting a syntax error even though it looks right to me: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '.'.`